# Page stops responding and freezes while sending continuous request to web server from ajax

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to create a signal on the webpage and display green or red color on the basis of values retrieved from a database. But when I'm sending request after 10 seconds page seems to be freezed and not responding. I'm unable to find out where I'm going wrong, please help me to resolve this problem.

Techstack Using - HTML, CSS, Js, Ajax, Python(Flask) and PostgreSQL

```
function latest_status(){

    var header = document.getElementById("circle");

    var tbid = $('#mtb').val();

    var signal = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/status?tbid='+tbid,
        data: "",
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        async:false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
        },
        //error: function(data) {
        //  alert("Data Not received !!");
        //},
        complete: function(data){
            setTimeout(latest_status, 10000);
        }
    });

    var signaldata = JSON.parse(signal.responseText);

    var signalvalue = signaldata[0].signalvalue;
    var datevalue = signaldata[0].date;

    if(signalvalue == '1')
    {
        header.style.background = "green";
    }
    else
    {
        header.style.background = "red";
    }
};

setTimeout(latest_status, 10000);
```

Flask Code :

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import jsonify
import json
import eventlet

from collections import OrderedDict

import psycopg2

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'project!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/status', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def latest_status():

    tbid = request.args['tbid']

    if request.method == 'POST':

        connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres", password = "abcd",host = "localhost",port = "5432", database="mydb")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        sql1 = "Select * from hst_vw where tb_id = %s"

        record_to_update = (tbid,)

        cursor.execute(sql1,record_to_update)
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        connection.commit()

        status_arr = []

        for i in record:
            hs = OrderedDict()
            hs["signalvalue"] = i[0]
            hs["date"] = i[1]
            hs["tbid"] = i[2]

            status_arr.append(hs)


        json_date = json.dumps(status_arr, default = str)

        return json_date

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: Can you show us your FLASK code please?

Comment: @Tobin I have added the flask code, please have a look. Kindly help me in resolving this issue which freezes my screen and take a long time to respond

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `setTimeout(latest_status, 10000);` inside success block then it will run once the request is completed so your code will look something like this.

```
var signal = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/status?tbid='+tbid,
    data: "",
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    async:false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        setTimeout(latest_status, 10000);
    },
});
```

I hope this will help.